# Function replacing_list(list_1, value1, value2) where value1 has to be replaced by value2 in list_1

Tags: python

I am having hard time figuring this out. I'm trying make a function replacing_list(list_1, value1, value2) where value1 has to be replaced by value2 in list_1. It should look like this:

```
>>> list_1 = [[[7]], 8]

>>> print(replacing_list(list_1, 7, 'a'))

[[['a']], 8]

>>> list_1

[[[7]], 8]

>>> print(replacing_list([1, 2, 3, [1, 2], 3, [[[1]]], [], 2], 1, 'x'))

['x', 2, 3, ['x', 2], 3, [[['x']]], [], 2]

>>> print(replacing_list([3, [33, [333, [13], 13]], 36], 3, 'q'))

['q', [33, [333, [13], 13]], 36]

>>> print(replacing_list([3, [33, [333, [13], 13]], 36], [13], 'm'))

[3, [33, [333, 'm', 13]], 36]
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you provide the detail of what your `replacing_list` function is doing?

Comment: Basically it replaces items in list_1 -  items which are value1 have to be replaced by items value2. Let's say that your list_1 is: [[[7]], 8]   and value1 is 7 and value2 is 'a'. Then you should get this: [[['a']], 8]

Comment: I can see what your problem statement is, you've clearly stated what outputs should be generated by what inputs, but you don't show what the inside of your `replacing_list` function looks like so we can help address your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am explicitly testing the type; but I think there can be a better way. Nevertheless, it is working on lists. It is recursion.

```
def rep(l,v1,v2):
    for i,j in enumerate(l):
        if j == v1:
            l[i] = v2
        if type(j) == list:
            l[i] = rep(l[i],v1,v2)
    return l

>>> rep([3, [33, [333, [13], 13]], 36], [13], 'm')
[3, [33, [333, 'm', 13]], 36]
```

Comment: But the original list has to remain unchanged.

Comment: @qwerty1 So just make a copy of it; by l_copy = l[:]; before doing that process

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
def replacing_list(lst, to_replace, replacement):
    result = []
    for e in lst:
        if e == to_replace:
            result.append(replacement)
        elif isinstance(e, list):
            result.append(replacing_list(e, to_replace, replacement))
        else:
            result.append(e)
    return result


print(replacing_list([[[7]], 8], 7, 'a'))
print(replacing_list([1, 2, 3, [1, 2], 3, [[[1]]], [], 2], 1, 'x'))
print(replacing_list([3, [33, [333, [13], 13]], 36], 3, 'q'))
print(replacing_list([3, [33, [333, [13], 13]], 36], [13], 'm'))
```

**Output**

```
[[['a']], 8]
['x', 2, 3, ['x', 2], 3, [[['x']]], [], 2]
['q', [33, [333, [13], 13]], 36]
[3, [33, [333, 'm', 13]], 36]
```

Note that `replacing_list` does not change the original list.